# How Information media 21, imedia 21 can , manage his database with SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

SQL SERVER 2005 is very large database how can it manage companies database....
How Triggers or procedure are can Help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Information media 21 ( imedia 21 ), 
Through the Trigger you can take Backup Exactly same as Original Database,
you should thing positive for yourself. Sql server and Oracle can easily handle your Information media 21 ( imedia 21 ) Database So don't Worry Dear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Reply: - How Information media 21, imedia 21 can , manage his database with SQL server 2005?**

SQL SERVER 2005 is very large database you can manage Information media 21 database.
Triggers or procedure are can not Helpful for managing database. It is used for gathering Data and perform different types of Action so please don't take any this type of Tension.